# Best Practice to build schema database for my case

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working in an application with big database and I'm suffering for slow some of my query.

So , I need to give me some advicess for changing the schema if I need.

I hava an application about Transaction and Invoices, each invoice has more than 100-250 transactions.

So , I have a query to get all invoices and sum the amount of transaction.

this query take more than 10s to run.

Can you give me an advice to improve this query.

this query will get 10k invoices and each invoice has 100-250 transaction

```
SELECT id, amount, (
  select sum(amount)
  from transactions
  where invoice_id = invoices.id
) as paid from invoices
```

thanks

Comment: Doesn't really sound like there's anything wrong with your structure. Looks like a typical one-to-many relationship

Comment: Share `transactions` table structure

Comment: I thought maybe if I added new column in Invoice Table (Total_Paid) and it will be updated after any new transaction. It will make the query faster

Answer (score 2):

use join and in case if you have no foreign key relationship with transactions table then create that relationship with invoices table

```
SELECT id,sum(amount)
 from invoices i join transactions t on t.invoice_id = i.id
group by id
```

Comment: OP should also ensure that `transaction (invoice_id)` is a foreign key to `invoice (id)`

Comment: @Phil it seems me op already has that relation though i assume it by seeing his query

Comment: We don't know for sure so I thought it might be worth pointing out

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin . . . This query will not include invoices that have no transactions.  The OPs does include these.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine logically.  I would write it as:

```
select i.id, i.amount,
       (select sum(t.amount)
        from transactions t
        where t.invoice_id = i.id
       ) as paid
from invoices i;
```

For performance, you want an index on `transactions(invoice_id, amount)`:

```
create index idx_transaction_invoice_amount on transactions(invoice_id, amount);
```